# How to reduce size of my RDS mySql database of 5000 GB to 2000 GB, with all the triggers and functions intact?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a RDS MySql database of provisioned storage 5000 GiB. Out of 5000 GiB I am using only 1400 GiB and want to reduce size of provisioned storgae to 2000 GiB. All the tables are innoDb.

I want to keep my triggers, indexes, keys and functions intact.

What will be the simplest and most fail proof approach to achieve this ?

Comment: I recommend you keep closer to 2x.  Filling 1400 out of 2000 is rather tight.  It will prevent certain maintenance operations.

Comment: You should probably change the title -- I think you are trying to save money by paying for less RAM, not shrink the database.

Answer (score 1):

According to Amazon's documentation for RDS storage:

> You can't reduce the amount of storage for a DB instance after storage
> has been allocated.

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html

If you really need to reduce the storage, then it sounds like you would have to spin up a completely new RDS instance and migrate your entire database, then shutdown the original instance entirely.

Comment: If that uses a disk snapshot, it won't shrink the disk usage.  That is, you will continue to use 1400 GiB.

Comment: Good point. You would have to do an export/import to move your data and other objects if you wanted to recover any space.